# If I have multiple entries in a cloumn in mysql that need to be changed

Tags: mysql, insert-update

So I want to change all the fields in the column allow_two_day_ordering to False. How can I change them all without doing it one by one. I have a much bigger list than this.

```
+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
| ID    | Venue_id                             | allow_two_day_ordering |
+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
| 26862 | 099B4758-2D0B-E411-9406-00155DCFC111 | TRUE                   |
| 26865 | 4fcdf8dd-2f0b-e411-9406-00155dcfc111 | TRUE                   |
| 26868 | 9e4b1850-330b-e411-9406-00155dcfc111 |                        |
| 26871 | bb0ed477-360b-e411-9406-00155dcfc111 | TRUE                   |
| 26874 | 89d6b4c7-350b-e411-9406-00155dcfc111 |                        |
| 26877 | a40d0646-340b-e411-9406-00155dcfc111 | TRUE                   |
| 26880 | e6693bac-330b-e411-9406-00155dcfc111 | TRUE                   |
```

I think my query would be something like so:

UPDATE venue_locations set allow_two_day_ordering = FALSE WHERE ID = '26862,26865,26868';

Like so?

Comment: Just leave out the `WHERE` clause and it will update all rows.

Comment: UPDATE venue_locations set allow_two_day_ordering = False;
  Like he mentioned, if you don't specify a WHERE statement it does EVERYTHING in the column.

Of note .. I think there is a difference between col = "false" and col = false ..

Comment: @easleyfixed would the query above work for those three ID's and if i wanted more I would just keep adding them.. the other id's?

Comment: It should work for any row in the table at the time of execution.  In an update to what I mentioned above too,  x = "true" is a string and x holds the word "true" in it.  But x = true, is truth .. the VALUE of x is TRUE .. if that makes sense .. the "" and '' matter.

Comment: @easleyfixed But this would only update 3 rows correct, the three rows with the id's in hte where clause? UPDATE venue_locations set allow_two_day_ordering = FALSE WHERE ID = '26862,26865,26868';

Comment: WHERE ID = '26862' OR ID = '26865' OR ID='26868';

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to set **all** the values to `false` you can do this:

```
UPDATE venue_locations set allow_two_day_ordering = FALSE;
```

Note: No `WHERE` clause, so all rows will be selected.

[Update, in response to question updates]

If you have a list you can do this:

```
UPDATE venue_locations set allow_two_day_ordering = FALSE WHERE ID IN (26862,26865,26868);
```

The `IN` clause can work well for short lists and smaller tables. It can be slow for larger tables, but for a one-time update it'll probably be acceptable.

If you want to reset all the `TRUE` values to `FALSE`:

```
UPDATE venue_locations set allow_two_day_ordering = FALSE where allow_two_day_ordering = TRUE;
```

Comment: Well just the ones in an array... so I would set WHERE and then list id's?

Comment: Like for instance say just those 5 that have TRUE next to them now.

Comment: That's two different questions. Be clear about what you want to achieve, or you're not going to get useful answers. If you have a list of IDs then that's one solution. If you just want to reset all the `TRUE` values, that's a different solution.

Comment: Is it not `WHERE ID IN ('26862','26865','26868');` instead of `WHERE ID IN '26862,26865,26868';`?

Comment: @FanoFN Yes, of course. Phone ringing while I typed the answer